# google app engine cloud sql connection never closes

Tags: jdbc, server, google-cloud-sql, google-app-engine

I`m in the development stage of an app and I don't make many server\cloud sql calls but for some reason I have an average of 400 usage hours a month.

When I look at the cloud sql active connections dashboard I see there is always at least one active connection but in the read\write operations it's usually on 0 besides the occasional small bumps.

I create a new connection each time I make a request to the server\cloud sql and close the connection each time when I return the response.

**the connection code is(I followed the guestbook tutorial\example)**

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
this.dbUrl  = "jdbc:google:mysql://trivia9991:triviadb?user=root";
this.dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
```

**the closing connection code is**

```
this.dbConn.close();
```

How can this keep a connection open at all time?

Answer (score 1):

If the connection close code is actually running this should not be the issue.  You should make sure that the connection is closed even if an exception occurs before hand.

It is also possible that a connection you made using the MySQL command line client is still open.

You can examine what connections are open by connecting using the MySQL command line client and running a `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` statement.

Comment: Thanks @David, I `ll add closing connection even if an exception occurs. But this is not the case here, I`m sure the connection close command is running(I have debug printouts) and still I have 3 active connections when there are no requests running and only two connections in the show processlist, one is the show query and the other is in sleep command